# How to configure project to use multiple stripe webhooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, webhooks

Hello I recently install the payment system stripe in my project ruby ​​on rails and after installation configuration and test I decided to set up the return webhook that I also perform successfully. But after a few updates in the projects I realized that I finally needed two webhook endpoints instead of just one as I had before. The first had to be used to retrieve the event when a resource is purchased and the other when a course is purchased. So I created in the stripe dashboad a new endpoint that has its own signing_key. So my problem is how to cofigure my project to use both endpoints and how to specify which endpoints to go to when the specified action occurs.

**config/secret.yml**

```
yml
development:
stripe_ressource_payement_signing_secret : 'whsec_.....'
stripe_course_payement_signing_secret : 'whsec_.......'
```

**config/initializers/stripe.rb**

```
StripeEvent.signing_secrets = [
    Rails.application.secrets.stripe_ressource_payement_signing_secret,
    Rails.application.secrets.stripe_course_payement_signing_secret,
]
```

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear, but I assume you have payment intents/charges for entities you call `resources` and `courses`? And you would like to receive events to 2 different webhooks endpoint depending if for example a charge was done for a `course` or `resource`?
If that is the case, that is not how it should work and I can explain further.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear enough. but your understanding is good. I have two entities races and resources for which I receive payments and I want to receive the events for each entity in two different webhook endpoint I went through the documentation of stripe and especially the chapter "Support for multiple signing secrets" available on this link: [link](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) and that's from what I put up the code snippets present above

Comment: TIL! I checked the gem quickly and I think all it does is allowing you to have multiple webhooks with multiple secrets (by default it is one only) and it eases processing of events by allowing you to process them with different classes easily configurable with `StripeEvent.configure do |events| ...`

Comment: Still, events you will receive from stripe will be the same `charge.captured` no matter if you have the charge captured for a race or resource. The way you can distinguish the two are via the event metadata, you can retrieve the charge by id from the event and it will have the metadata as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object

Comment: Then you configure different webhooks to process different data as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/object (see enabled_events). And then Stripe sends you events you defined on the webhook URI you defined.

I really hope this helps a bit. Also, if you have Stripe engineers available to help you - use them - documentation is extensive but still some things can be confusing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the explanations, I think that's what I missed. So effectively thanks to that I could understand the system and put everything in place and currently all walks as I want it thank you.

Comment: happy to help! good luck further